# Average of result set row

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, rdbms

I have a table of bandwidth utilization data. Each row has a hostname,niccardname, utilization percentage and timestamp. At maximum timestamp for each host there can be different NIC cards.
So for Each host i want average % utilization of different NIC cards at maximum timestamp.

Below is my table structure , insertions and queries -

```
CREATE TABLE bandwith_utilization
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  hostname character varying(255),
  "timestamp" bigint,
  niccardname character varying(255),
  percentageutilization integer,
  CONSTRAINT bandwidth_utilization_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE bandwith_utilization
  OWNER TO postgres;


INSERT INTO bandwith_utilization
VALUES (1,'host1','111111','nic1',40);
INSERT INTO bandwith_utilization
VALUES (2,'host1','111112','nic1',50);
INSERT INTO bandwith_utilization
VALUES (3,'host1','111113','nic1',50);
INSERT INTO bandwith_utilization
VALUES (4,'host1','111113','nic2',70);

INSERT INTO bandwith_utilization
VALUES (5,'host2','111111','nic1',80);
INSERT INTO bandwith_utilization
VALUES (6,'host2','111112','nic1',20);
INSERT INTO bandwith_utilization
VALUES (7,'host2','111112','nic2',30);

INSERT INTO bandwith_utilization
VALUES (8,'host3','111115','nic1',10);
```

So this is my table after insertions -

```
id  hostname    timestamp   niccardname     percentageutilization
------------------------------------------------------------------
1;  "host1";    111111;     "nic1";         40
2;  "host1";    111112;     "nic1";         50
3;  "host1";    111113;     "nic1";         50
4;  "host1";    111113;     "nic2";         70

5;  "host2";    111111;     "nic1";         80
6;  "host2";    111112;     "nic1";         20
7;  "host2";    111112;     "nic2";         30

8;  "host3";    111115;     "nic1";         10
```

I have a query which gives my output for hostnames at max timestamp -

```
select hostname, timestamp, niccardname, percentageutilization
from report.bandwith_utilization
 where timestamp = (select max(timestamp)
                    from report.bandwith_utilization nwUtil
                    where nwUtil.hostname = report.bandwith_utilization.hostname
                   ) ;
```

output of above query is -

```
"host1";  111113; "nic1"; 50
"host1";  111113; "nic2"; 70

"host2";  111112; "nic1"; 20
"host2";  111112; "nic2"; 30

"host3";  111115; "nic1"; 10
```

So Now My Expected out put is average % utilization of different NIC cards for each host. i.e.

```
"host1";  111113; "nic1"; 60
"host2";  111112; "nic1"; 25
"host3";  111115; "nic1"; 10
```

How can i find final average output with in the same query which i mentioned above?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag.  This looks like Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be an AVG() and group by

```
select hostname,timestamp,min(niccardname), avg(percentageutilization )
from report.bandwith_utilization
where (timestamp,hostname, niccardname)   in (select max(timestamp) ,hostname, niccardname
from report.bandwith_utilization nwUtil 
where nwUtil.hostname= report.bandwith_utilization.hostname
group by  hostname, niccardname
) 
group by  hostname,timestamp
order by  hostname,timestamp
```

Comment: it gave me only max results not average. i.e 5 entries what i shown above not 3 entries with average as expected.

Comment: still the same result :(

Answer (score 1):

The following is a better way to get the rows at the maximum time stamp:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*,
             rank() over (partition by hostname order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from report.bandwith_utilization u
     ) u
where seqnum = 1;
```

Now, you can get what you want:

```
select u.hostname, u.timestamp, avg(percentageutilization)
from (select u.*,
             rank() over (partition by hostname order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from report.bandwith_utilization u
     ) u
where seqnum = 1
group by u.hostname, u.timestamp;
```

It doesn't make sense (to me) to include `niccardname` in the result set.  You can use `min(niccardname)` if you want one value or `array_agg(niccardname)` if you want all of them in an array.

Comment: you are right i should not include niccardname in the result set. Even i don't even need that. Coming to query what you told above, i could not understand much out of it, so i can just tell where it's failing at -     ERROR: syntax error at or near "order" (2nd Order which you used in query).

Comment: @Abhimanyu . . . That should be `partition by`.  I don't know why my pesky fingers did that.